# hyperref conflicts with todonotes and chemfig packages

Tags: tikz-pgf, hyperref, incompatibility, pgfmath

I'm using TexLive 2012 from the openSUSE buildservice publishing repository, and a document that would compile with TeXLive 2011 now effects error messages such as:

> Package PGF Math Error: The function `add' already exists.
>
> Package PGF Math Error: The function `subtract' already exists.

and so on.

This is caused by `todonotes` and `chemfig`, since both load `tikz`. Is there a way to resolve this conflict?

An example, as requested:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

The relevant excerpt of the log from texlive 2011:

```
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2007/07/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1)
))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
Package: pgffor 2010/03/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.18)
```

and that of the log from texlive 2012:

```
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2007/07/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1)
))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen142
\pgfmath@count=\count113
\pgfmath@box=\box35
\pgfmath@toks=\toks24
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks25
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks26
)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: 'Works for me'. Perhaps you could add `\listfiles` to your example and report what file list you get: I suspect a version conflict with a locally-installed version of one or more files.

Comment: Unfortunately the example doesn't produce any error even if I add `\usepackage{chemfig}`.

Comment: I just tried the MWE on texlive 2011 on another computer and it compiles fine. The diff of the logs merely indicates that /usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex is loaded twice, and in the one case this has no effect, while in the other the functions are defined twice. There are no locally-installed files that interfere with this.

Comment: I didn't edit the previous message in time. pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex is included twice when the error message appears, and only once in texlive 2011.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause is that the latest version of [pgf](http://perso.enstimac.fr/~gaborit/latex/pgf_2.10-CVS.tds.zip) has the line

```
\RequirePackage{pgfmath}
```

in `tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty`. If I comment it out, then everything works fine.
[Here](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3568323&group_id=142562&atid=752792) is the bug report for this.